# What is a difference between CPU threads and program threads

Tags: multithreading, cpu

For example i5 7600k has 4 threads, but game can have more than 4 threads. What is the difference and why they have the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CPU that has 4 threads (really a CPU with 4 cores, or possibly a 2 core CPU with Hyperthreading) can execute 4 separate threads *simultaneously*.  A program can have more threads than that, but only 4 of them can be executing at any given time - the others would be in a sleep/wait state while they wait for the CPU to become available.

As for how the CPU "becomes available" for other threads when there are more threads than it can execute at a given time, that's a function of the operating system scheduler.  The operating system scheduler rotates threads on and off the CPU periodically (typically every few milliseconds) so that every thread that wants to execute eventually gets its turn on the CPU.

There's more to it than that, but hopefully that covers the gist of your question.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it now.